# Multiple Login table in yii2 IdentityInterface error while login

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I have 2 different tables `user` and `organiser` and i am trying to create 2 different login for both users.

I am able to sign them up easily and get the record in database but after saving the record i get the error on following code line

```
if ($user = $model->signup()) {
           if (Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user)) { //yii\web\IdentityInterface error
                return $this->goHome();
            }
        }
```

Following is my `configuration` module

```
    'components' => [
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'identityCookie' => [
            'name' => '_frontendOrganiser', // unique for frontend
        ],
    ],
    'users' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\User',
        'identityClass' => 'common\models\Users',
        'enableAutoLogin' => false,
        'enableSession' => true,
        'identityCookie' => [
            'name' => '_frontendUser', // unique for frontend
        ],
    ],

    'session' => [
        'name' => 'PHPFRONTSESSID',
        'savePath' => sys_get_temp_dir(),
    ],
]
```

So what is wrong am i doing here? Do i need to create any other Interface or something or provide different interface for different module?

And i had to do this because `organiser` table uses `password_hash` technique to log in the users where my `user` table is from another project and they uses `md5` technique, so i had to create separate module for both users.

> Argument 1 passed to yii\web\User::login() must be an instance of yii\web\IdentityInterface, instance of common\models\Users given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\frontend\controllers\SiteController.php on line 202 and defined

The exact error statement is as above.

Comment: Is your `$user` variable an object of class that `implements yii\web\IdentityInterface`?

Comment: @PatrykRadziszewski yeah thats it. That was the problem. But i am able to log in now but cant access logged in user with `Yii::$app->users->identity->username` line.

Answer (score 0):

I think your user model don't implement the Identity interface correctly.

Try check you data model also (in your DB) this must contain all the field managed bay the interface.

And be sure you User implement the Identity Interface correctly.
and mapping the interface method with your model correctly..

See the interface doc for this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-identityinterface.html